# jQuery parse JSON returned from WEB API

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-web-api2

I have an WEB API 2 that returns a json.

I'm trying to parse that json returned by the web api, but I have some hard time understanding what means `$F_1`

[image]

As you can see in the picture, I use jQuery `each` to iterate through the data returned ...

How can I parse the $F_1 result? And why is named $F_1?

Comment: What is your server code, that returns JSON? How do you get this JSON on client? If this is an ajax request - what it looks like?

Comment: The web api returns proper JSON (I tested it), the call instead is done from within SharePoint using a proxy. Therefore Sharepoint is "messing" up a bit with the response ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. As it is a proxy call from within SharePoint, the result can be parsed like this:

```
var val = JSON.parse(data.get_body());

var msg = '';

$.each(val, function (index, value) 
{
    msg += value.PropertyName;

});
```